# Linear algebra : when looking for the solution set of $Mx = b$, can one deduce the " particular solution" from the null space?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

[In order to make the question more precise, as required by comments].

In this question, I assume the equation $Mx= b$ is consistent.

---

Suppose I'm looking for the solution set of a matrix  equation $Mx = b$ with a fixed  $b\neq 0$.

Suppose I already have the solution set of the equation $Mx = 0$ , that is , I know the null space  of matrix $M$ and can express it as the span of some determined vectors.

Since any solution of the first equation is of the form : $s = n+ p$ where $n$ is a member of the null space  of matrix $M$ ( and therefore the member of some span I know) , and $p$ is the "particular solution" , is it possible, knowing the null space, to determine $p$ directly, without having to solve the system $Mx=b$ , which requires to bring the augmented matrix $[M|b]$ to its row reduced echelon form.

In short: having already solved the system $Mx = 0$ , can I directly find the particular solution required to express the solution set of $Mx= b , b \neq 0$?

Comment: Mustn't you somehow determine whether Mx = b has even one solution , first?

Comment: The answer is *no*. The nullspace tells you solutions of $Mx=0$ and this won't help you even decide if $Mx=b$ has a solution in general.

Comment: @311411 - Question edited in order to restrict the scope of question.

Comment: Another way to see why this is not true is by considering a matrix $M$ with trivial null space. If your question would have a positive answer, then we could solve $Mx = b$ for all $b$ very quickly for nonsingular matrices.

Comment: The null space doesn't change when you change $b$, so it is impossible to deduce a particular solution from the null space.

Comment: you can spare some time in simultaneous solving for 0 and b, but otherwise the solution for 0 does nothing to find the solution to Mx=b

Comment: You can use knowledge of the null space to reduce the number of variables by paramterizing $\vec x$ to be orthogonal to the null space. For instance, if your matrix is $3 \times 3$ and your null space is a plane with normal vector $\vec n$ , then your particular solution would need to have the form $\vec x = t\vec n$ and you could find the single variable $t$ by solving
$$\bigg( M \vec n\bigg ) t = \vec b $$